# Emacs replacing require with autoload

Tags: emacs, melpa

After profiling my Emacs init file, I saw that many of my modes are taking a long time to load, explaining why I've been having slow start times.

I am trying to use after-load or autoload to decrease the load time but have been unsuccessful in many modes.

For example, I have a mode called `multiple-cursors.el` that I downloaded manually and placed in my `.emacs.d` directory. Here is the code I have now:

```
;; Multiple Cursors                                                               
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/multiple-cursors.el/")
(require 'multiple-cursors)  
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'mc/edit-lines)                                     
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c .") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c ,") 'mc/mark-previous-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c /") 'mc/mark-all-like-this)
```

I tried to replace the `require` line with `(autoload 'multiple-cursors-mode "multiple-cursors.el" "Multiple cursors mode")` but that did not work.

This format of the autoload seems to work well only with Melpa-installed packages. How can I do the equivalent for manually installed packages, such as the example above?

Comment: There is no such thing as `multiple-cursors-mode`, that you should autoload.  You need to add autoloads for all `mc/…` functions you'd like to use.  You should probably just use package.el instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write autoloads for the functions that you are actually calling through the key bindings (i.e. `mc/edit-lines`, `mc/mark-next-like-this`, `mc/mark-previous-like-this` and `mc/mark-all-like-this`), since that's how the loading of the file is triggered.  The autoloads need to refer to the files where the respective functions are defined, which is `mc-edit-lines` for `mc/edit-lines`, and `mc-mark-more` for the others.

So after setting the load path and binding the keys, add something like this:

```
(autoload 'mc/edit-lines "mc-edit-lines" "" t)
(autoload 'mc/mark-next-like-this "mc-mark-more" "" t)
(autoload 'mc/mark-previous-like-this "mc-mark-more" "" t)
(autoload 'mc/mark-all-like-this "mc-mark-more" "" t)
```

Comment: So I would still do the same thing: add path and require, then set the global keys. But add the autoload at the end of all that?

Comment: Well, except the `require`, which shouldn't be needed with the autoloads.

Comment: Yep, that worked! Finally understand this part. Thanks a lot!